# Can't access WordPress Dashboard in an iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe, x-frame-options

I have an iframe on http://foo.example.com which targets to http://bar.example.com.

On http://bar.example.com is a WordPress installation. I'm able to view the page and click on all pages and post but when I try to go to the backend I get

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

and the request is aborted.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options) I aded this header which gets send successfully:

```
header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');
```

What else can limit the access to just the dashboard (and the login screen)?

I have access to both subdomains and can use a htaccess as well

Comment: Take a look here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/81607/12615

Comment: Yep, exactly! Can you provide a answer to accept or should this question get closed cause it's obviously a duplicate?

Comment: Different sites, not a duplicate. I'll make a summary here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this, in WordPress Answers, [Receiving “This content cannot be displayed in a frame” error on login page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/81611/12615), WordPress sends a special header

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

that prevents [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking#Server_and_client). And hence, embedding the admin as an iframe.

It is possible to eliminate this header removing a couple of actions from `wp-includes/default-filters.php`, but at your own risk.

> Someone might register a domain with a very similar name, embed your login as background iframe and log the login credentials when you try to type them in.

**Please, read the full Q&A at WPSE.**

Answer (score 8):

Here is a better solution that won't break when you update Wordpress:

```
remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );
remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );
```

Here's another solution if you're using Apache. Throw this in your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset X-Frame-Options
    Header always unset X-Frame-Options
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This was a perfect solution, Thanks!

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. I forgot to mention people need to throw the remove_action calls in `functions.php`